# Agent Analyst/Agent-Based Modeling in ArcGIS Book Chapter 6 implementation problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, java, agent-analyst, agent-based-modeling

I want to study on Agent Based Modeling in ArcGIS with Agent Analyst extension. I'm doing the tutorials of the book that is written by Kevin M.Johnston (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/agent-analyst/) In Chapter 6 there is an exercise about agents on network. I'm not experienced on Java therefore I can not make a comment about the errors Java give. I want to implement the codes on sample work into my study with changing the destination paths and parameters (Figures below).

[image]

[image]

It is compiled but it gives the error below.

"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Active"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:388)
    at java.lang.Float.(Float.java:489)
    at default_package.Exercise3.setupPlaces(Unknown Source)
    at default_package.Exercise3.initAgents(Unknown Source)
    at default_package.Exercise3._build(Unknown Source)
    at uchicago.src.simbuilder.base.gis.GISSimModelImpl.begin(GISSimModelImpl.java:107)
    at uchicago.src.sim.engine.BaseController.beginModel(BaseController.java:331)
    at uchicago.src.sim.engine.AbstractGUIController.beginModel(AbstractGUIController.java:218)
    at uchicago.src.sim.engine.Controller.beginModel(Controller.java:646)
    at uchicago.src.sim.engine.BaseController.startSim(BaseController.java:346)
    at uchicago.src.sim.engine.Controller.startSim(Controller.java:602)
    at uchicago.src.sim.engine.Controller$2.actionPerformed(Controller.java:388)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6297)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6062)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4660)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4236)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4166)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:647)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:645)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:644)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)"

[image]

Is there any one encountered this problem?

Comment: Please always present any code and error messages as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches by anyone with the same problem.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/48623517/820534

Answer (score 1):

Due to my limited Java experience I can't really completely help you unfortunately, but seeing the answer is taking a bit of time, I hope to be able to get you on your way again.

The actual error is in the first line:

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Active"
```

Where [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)  is the error you're looking for. In the second line we can see what the problem is:

```
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
```

Where FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString comes up. At this point I'm not sure, I'm guessing that it is expecting a decimal (float) input, but getting something else? I would suggest reading further [into this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=readJavaFormatString), for a possible answer.

Otherwise: as Java is an object-oriented language try to use your IDE's debugger to step into the error and see what object is "Active" at the moment the error is thrown.

It might also be better to ask this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead, where the actual Java programmers are at. Java is used very little in GIS (from personal experience).